# Computing the set difference among two consecutive rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, set

I need some tips to make a calculation.

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
text_id     name     date                words
1           John     2018-01-01          {ocean, blue}
1           John     2018-02-01          {ocean, green} 
2           Anne     2018-03-01          {table, chair}
3           Anne     2018-03-01          {hot, cold, warm}
3           Mark     2018-04-01          {hot, cold}
3           Ethan    2018-05-01          {warm, icy}
4           Paul     2018-01-01          {cat, dog, puppy}
4           John     2018-02-01          {cat}
5           Paul     2018-03-01          {cat, sheep, deer}
```

In the text, the `text_id` stands for an specific text (SAME TEXT_ID = SAME TEXT). The `name` column stands for the person that has edited the text. The `date` column stands for the date in which the user made the edit. The `words` column is composed by the words that form the text after the users edit.

The `words` column is a set. I need to add an aditional column, `added_words`, which contains the set difference of the previous edit on **THE SAME** text. This is in order to check whats the difference between one edit and its consecutive one **IN THE SAME TEXT**.

The sample output here would be:

```
text_id     name     date          words            added_words
1           John     2018-01-01    {ocean,blue}     {ocean, blue}
1           John     2018-02-01    {ocean,green}    {green}
2           Anne     2018-03-01    {table,chair}    {table, chair}
3           Anne     2018-03-01    {hot,cold,warm}  {hot, cold, warm}
3           Mark     2018-04-01    {hot,cold}       {}
3           Ethan    2018-05-01    {warm,icy}       {warm, icy}
4           Paul     2018-01-01    {cat,dog,puppy}  {cat, dog, puppy}
4           John     2018-02-01    {cat}            {}
5           Paul     2018-03-01    {cat,sheep,deer} {cat,sheep,deer}
```

Note that basically, the `added_words` column contains the set difference among the words column in row `i` and words column in row `i-1`, **only if the text_id in row i and row i-1 is the same**, because: I only want the difference among the SAME text (same `text_id`), not different ones.

Any tips on this will be extremely helpful.

**EDIT**:

In order to turn the `words` column into a set, do:

> df['words'] = df['words'].str.strip('{}').str.split(',').apply(set)

Comment: This would be easier to reproduce if you made your data availble through `pd.DataFrame..`, since you're making use of sets. If we copy this now, we get `str`

Comment: Done. Now you can turn the words column into a set

Comment: The output for `5` seems incorrect.  Did you copy the data wrong?

Comment: Nope, it is not incorrect. Note that it is a different text, as its text_id is 5, not 4. Thus, it is a new text.

Comment: I get that.. But how does `boo` change to `cat, sheep, deer`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I decided to change the output to make it more representative, but forgot to change it in the given dataframe sample. Now I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `diff` and `fillna`. `Diff` will do set subtraction

```
df['added_words'] = df.groupby('text_id').words.diff().fillna(df.words)

In [162]: df
Out[162]:
   text_id   name        date               words         added_words
0        1   John  2018-01-01       {ocean, blue}       {ocean, blue}
1        1   John  2018-02-01      {green, ocean}             {green}
2        2   Anne  2018-03-01      {chair, table}      {chair, table}
3        3   Anne  2018-03-01   {warm, cold, hot}   {warm, cold, hot}
4        3   Mark  2018-04-01         {cold, hot}                  {}
5        3  Ethan  2018-05-01         {warm, icy}         {warm, icy}
6        4   Paul  2018-01-01   {cat, puppy, dog}   {cat, puppy, dog}
7        4   John  2018-02-01               {cat}                  {}
8        5   Paul  2018-03-01  {cat, deer, sheep}  {cat, deer, sheep}
```

Comment: This helped very much. I get the expected output. How would you do it in order to compute the words that were erased, instead of the new ones?

Comment: @HRDSL: I haven't seen your comment until today. Just for clarification on meaning of `erased words`,  is it the intersection/common words between 2 sets? for example:  `{green, ocean}` and `{ocean, blue}`. Is it `ocean` ?

Comment: Nope, in that example, the erased word would be green, because it is in the first set, but not in the second.

Comment: @HRDSL: hmm... I am kind of confused because the current solution already provided `green` as the output. I guess a detail sample and desired output will clear up everything, but the comment doesn't have space for that. Please post a new question with your desired output. You may link back to this post for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have sets, we can get the difference of those by simply substracting them with `shift`, while using `groupby`:

```
df['added_words'] = df.groupby('text_id')\
                      .apply(lambda x: (x['words'] - x['words'].shift()).fillna(x['words']))\
                      .to_numpy()
```

*note: if you have `pandas < 0.24.0` use `.values` instead of `to_numpy()`*

---

**Output**

```
   text_id   name        date               words         added_words
0        1   John  2018-01-01       {blue, ocean}       {blue, ocean}
1        1   John  2018-02-01      {ocean, green}             {green}
2        2   Anne  2018-03-01      {table, chair}      {table, chair}
3        3   Anne  2018-03-01   {hot, warm, cold}   {hot, warm, cold}
4        3   Mark  2018-04-01         {hot, cold}                  {}
5        3  Ethan  2018-05-01         {icy, warm}         {icy, warm}
6        4   Paul  2018-01-01   {cat, puppy, dog}   {cat, puppy, dog}
7        4   John  2018-02-01               {cat}                  {}
8        5   Paul  2018-03-01  {cat, sheep, deer}  {cat, sheep, deer}
```

Comment: this one didn't work for me. It doesn't compute the difference (I don't even know what it computes).